# How can I block Facebook (or any site) permanently, and/or almost-permanently?

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, osx-mavericks

this is a relevant programming question because it involves tweaking low-level things on my laptop.

I want to break some addictions, which requires blocking some sites permanently (like Buzzfeed, etc), and making some sites very, very difficult to get to (like Facebook, which I might need one day so can't block permanently).

I'm looking for something stronger than a hosts file solution, which hasn't worked because it's too easy to change. A browser-level solution is too weak as well. What would be more of a pain to undo?

I'd prefer to block sites on my laptop, rather than on the router level, so it both works everywhere I go and doesn't interfere with others' access on my network. Surely there's some lower-level way to do this than the hosts file - or maybe some way to encrypt the hosts file - any ideas?

Thank you!

Katie

Comment: You can’t do this yourself, because if you do the block you will be able to undo it.

Answer (score -2):

You nailed the idea with the hosts file. DNS is the way to go and the host file is the first line in that process. Next, I would recommend using child blocking tools which will allow you to create a password to block items. If you make the password a very long/ridiculous and not digitally save it, the time it takes to plug it in would be a deterrent. You can also block sites from your home router, or better yet, call up your ISP. They are well acquainted with blocking sites and you would have 0 control to circumvent except using different internet. Good Luck!

PS. if you can edit your hosts file then you are running admin level access. First, if you are on windows, never run as admin! Its the number one security flaw. create an admin account and downgrade yours. You would then need the admin password to change it. Like before, make it ridiculously long and don't save it digitally.

Comment: Your comment is wrong on so many levels. 1) Being able to edit hosts file != running as admin. It can be granted temporarily. Secondly, saving an admin password digitally is not bad practice (doing it unencrypted however is). Also, you can't call up your ISP and ask them to block sites. Christ...

Comment: First, your reading is wrong on so many levels. I said "running admin level access" (e.g. Sudo or Run as Admin) Second, saving a password digitally makes it trivial to alter the hosts file, not having it digitally makes it a pain, which is what this person wants. Third, Comcast is more than happy to block sites; sounds like you've never asked. Finally, your behavior is indicative of high stress or low age, so please check yourself before further commenting.